# Creating list for Pandas_datareader symbol warning

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

How can i create a list which would log the symbols for each symbol warning ?
Everytime I execute `data = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)` i get symbol warnings, i want to create a list of symbols which i got the warning for how can i do that?

```
SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol: 'BRK.B', replacing with NaN.
  warnings.warn(msg.format(sym), SymbolWarning)
```

Full code :

```
start = datetime.date(2008,11,1)
end = datetime.date.today()
# df = web.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start, end)
df = web.DataReader(tickers, 'yahoo', start, end)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like yahoo in your case is rejecting requests after a set limit.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same error. Basically we need to catch the warnings and extract the symbols from it.

Easier said than done.. I wasn't able to do it with `try` & `except`. (*If anybody was able to, please let me know..*).

I found out [warnings](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/warnings.py#LC420) had a `catch_warnings` subclass (*context manager*) which I can use to capture the warning messages and extract the symbols from them.

The way I did (*maybe not the best way*):

```
import warnings
import pandas_datareader

list_ = ["AAPL","TSLA","XYZ","QUAL","IOV"]  # Sample list of symbols
bad_symbol_list=[]

df = pandas_datareader.yahoo.daily.YahooDailyReader(list_, start='2008-01-11',end='2020-01-31', interval='d')

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as err:

    warnings.resetwarnings()
    df_processed=df.read()
    
    for w in err:
        print(w.message)
        tmp = w.message.args[0].replace("'","")
        bad_symbol_list +=[ tmp.split(" ")[4].replace("," , "") ]
    print(bad_symbol_list)
```

Output:

```
Failed to read symbol: 'XYZ', replacing with NaN.
Failed to read symbol: 'IOV', replacing with NaN.
['XYZ', 'IOV']
```